# Вывести Image в GridControl DevExpress

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

При отображении данных в GridControl столкнулся с такой сложностью:
Имеется свойство в в модели для получения изображения из byte[]:

```
        public Image ImgPhoto
        {
            get
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(this.Photo.Data);
                Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                return image;
            }
        }
```

Так вот, как мне вывести это изображение в GridControl. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Мне подсказали, что надо использовать BitmapImage вместо Image. Вдруг кому-то пригодится.

```
public BitmapImage ImgPhoto
        {
            get
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                stream.Write(this.Photo.Data, 0, this.Photo.Data.Length);
                stream.Position = 0;
                System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
                BitmapImage returnImage = new BitmapImage();
                returnImage.BeginInit();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                returnImage.StreamSource = ms;
                returnImage.EndInit();

                return returnImage;
            }
        }
```

Comment: WPF не умеет работать с этим классом вроде, используйте что-то из наследников ImageSource

Comment: @АндрейNOP Хммм. На WinForm такая реализация отлично работала. Так все же может кто сталкивался с выводом в GridControl изображения. Видел только примеры с byte[]

Comment: Пробуйте как здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9564425/6766879

Comment: @АндрейNOP Оооо...еть. Я то думал не так вывожу в GridControl. Спасибо большое, мне это помогло

Comment: Я вам предлагал взять реализацию из ответа, а не из вопроса там, в вопросе реализация кривоватая. Ну и здесь ответ надо оформить ответом, т.к. в будущем кто-то наткнется на этот топик и подумает что ответа нет не дочитав вопрос до конца.

Answer (score 0):

Если картинку нужно вывести в столбце таблицы, то попробуйте сделать это следующим образом:

```
<dxg:GridControl ...>
    <dxg:GridColumn Header="Изображение"
                            Binding="{Binding BitmapImageData}">
        <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <dxe:ImageEdit ShowMenuMode="Hover"  
                            Source="{Binding Value}" 
                            MaxHeight="500" 
                            MaxWidth="{Binding Width, ElementName=EditParamView}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
    </dxg:GridColumn>
</dxg:GridControl>
```